# Validations for unwanted codes during SVN commit

Tags: svn, eclipse-plugin, pre-commit-hook

How to validate whether checked-in file has certain unwanted codes before committing into SVN. Also need to enforce developers to follow certain common practices before checking in their changes.

This can be either with some eclipse plugin or with SVN alone.

For example:
I want to restrict developer’s to check-in Java code with System.out.println();

Comment: Your tag "pre-commit-hook" indicates you already know how to accomplish this at a high level: install a pre-commit hook on the server. What exactly is giving you trouble?

Answer (score 0):

Use pre-commit hook.
Install and write checks on basis of your server (Unix -> shell or Perl / Windows -> Bat file)